# Is Training Separate NER Models for Specific Labels a Viable Strategy for Improved Accuracy?

Tags: natural-language-processing, named-entity-recognition

In my project, I'm utilizing Named Entity Recognition (NER) to identify crucial variables in prompts categorized into specific domains. However, incorporating numerous labels in the training data has resulted in poor accuracy. Considering this, would creating separate NER models for each category be a  strategy to enhance accuracy and improve variable identification?

Comment: Please, add information of your neural network model structure, input data example, expected output, accuracy change, training parameters. These will help us to give you good suggestion.